# Geolocation API not working on some Android-devices

Tags: javascript, html, api, geolocation, phonegap-build

This is my first post on Stackoverflow.
I will describe my problem:

It is about an Phonegap Build-application in HTML and Javascript. I have two files:

"index.html" see source on http://pastebin.com/RCQruFkE

"config.xml" see source on http://pastebin.com/1xCvvHL1

We have two Android-devices:

1) Samsung Galaxy Y (Android OS 2.3.6)

2) Samsung Galaxy S2 (Android OS 4.1.2)

Also on my simulator, Android OS 4.3, it doesn't work.
You only see:
"Finding geolocation...".
On my Samsung Galaxy Y (2.3.6) you will succesfully see the geolocation (latitude and longitude and some other information).

I have also tried to use "cordova.js" with cordova 3.0.0 in it (JS) and without the file, makes no sense.

Does anyone have the same problem? It has been started last Thursday in the evening (then it worked) and Friday morning it didn't work anymore. Same APK!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding "enableHighAccuracy" and "timeout", i have seen this issue in some android devices where a timeout should be set to allow for geolocation services to work.

var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
};

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use http://ip-api.com/json . They provide latitude, longitude,  city, country etc

jQuery example:

```
$.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json",function(data){
     var lat = data.lat;
});
```

Their json output:

```
{"as":"AS10199 Tata Communications Ltd","city":"Pune","country":"India","countryCode":"IN","isp":"Tata Communications","lat":18.5333,"lon":73.8667,"org":"Tata Communications","query":"115.117.217.243","region":"MH","regionName":"Maharashtra","status":"success","timezone":"Asia/Kolkata","zip":"411001"}
```

It's that simple.

Answer (score 0):

You have referenced **cordova.js** but it should be **phonegap.js** when using PhoneGap Build

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Should Be

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:**

Here is a link to the [official](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/app-building) PGB boilerplate:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start/tree/master/www

See the contents of the index.html file.